# How to get average of columns in a pivot table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I just learnt the concept of pivot tables and someone helped me come up with this code to create one:(I added the code for average)

```
  SELECT  pvt.Fname,
            pvt.Lname,
            pvt.[English], 
            pvt.[Mathematics], 
            pvt.[Geography], 
            pvt.[Literature], 
            pvt.[French],
            TotalScore = ISNULL(pvt.[English], 0) + ISNULL(pvt.[Mathematics], 0) + ISNULL(pvt.[Geography], 0) + ISNULL(pvt.[Literature], 0) + ISNULL(pvt.[French], 0)

            AverageScore=AVG((pvt.[English]) + (pvt.[Mathematics]) + (pvt.[Geography]) +(pvt.[Literature])+(pvt.[French]))

    FROM    (   SELECT  s.SubjectName, er.Result, su.Fname, su.Lname 
                FROM    Subject AS s
                        INNER JOIN ExamResults AS er
                            ON s.SubjectID = er.SubjectID
                        INNER JOIN Exam AS e
                            ON er.ExamID = e.ExamID
                        LEFT JOIN Student AS su
                            ON er.StudentID = su.StudentID
                WHERE   e.Class = @Class
            ) AS e
            PIVOT 
            (   MAX([Result])
                FOR [SubjectName] IN ([English], [Mathematics], [Geography], [Literature], [French])
            ) AS pvt;




 Fname  |   Lname  | English | Mathematics | Geography | Literature | French | TotalScore| AverageScore
     -------+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------+-------------
    Earnest |   Baker  |   100   |     35      |      -    |     -      |   75   |     210    
     House  | Richards |    56   |      -      |     35    |     -      |   75   |     166
     Jacob  |    Jake  |    86   |     37      |      -    |     75     |    -   |     198
```

The four tables with their columns are as follows:

Subject table columns: **SubjectID,SubjectName**

Student table columns: **StudentID,Fname,Lname**

Exam table columns: **ExamID,ExamDate,ExamPeriod,Class**

ExamResults column: **ExamResultID,ExamID,StudentID,SubjectID,Result**

Problem is, the Average column is not returning any value. I'm using sql server. Please could you help me identify what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output

Comment: Try /5 instead of AVG

Comment: The tables are here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233022/how-can-i-show-the-subjects-as-column-headers-as-well-as-the-student-name-and-t
@NoDisplayName

Comment: At the time of summing up subjects in average function use "ISNULL" to avoid any summing errors. And to get average as SARATH said divide it by total number of subjects.

Comment: @SarathAvanavu - Good work. Even OP doesn't care to reply

Comment: I can't sum by the total number of subjects, because I want to skip over the values which are 0 or null...and @NoDisplayName, sorry about not posting the tables, it is because Sarath Avanavu pointed out the links before I could. I really I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Edrich - Thats what exactly am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to find the `total` and `average` of `results` in `Pivot` source query

```
SELECT pvt.Fname,
       pvt.Lname,
       pvt.[English],
       pvt.[Mathematics],
       pvt.[Geography],
       pvt.[Literature],
       pvt.[French],
       TotalScore,
       AverageScore
FROM   (SELECT s.SubjectName,
               er.Result,
               su.Fname,
               su.Lname,
               TotalScore = Sum(Result)OVER(partition BY Fname, Lname),
                AverageScore = Avg(Result)OVER(partition BY Fname, Lname)
               //AverageScore = Sum(Result)OVER(partition BY Fname, Lname)/5 If you want average for all the subjects
        FROM   Subject AS s
               INNER JOIN ExamResults AS er
                       ON s.SubjectID = er.SubjectID
               INNER JOIN Exam AS e
                       ON er.ExamID = e.ExamID
               LEFT JOIN Student AS su
                      ON er.StudentID = su.StudentID
        WHERE  e.Class = @Class) AS e
       PIVOT ( Max([Result])
             FOR [SubjectName] IN ([English],
                                   [Mathematics],
                                   [Geography],
                                   [Literature],
                                   [French]) ) AS pvt;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I'm getting an error: "Invalid column name 'Result'...and I want to average the subjects where the value is not null...I think Avg() should ignore those values? So I can't use the division by 5 in this case